# How to monitor a aws-python based application using APM tool?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, monitor, elastic-apm

I want to know if there's any way I can monitor my application using one of the open-source application monitoring (APM) tools. I don't have much knowledge about them, and got pretty confused when I searched for this, so asking it here. I tried SigNoz but it's not for windows and I work on windows os. I am looking for a tool that supports mac/windows/Linux. I am pretty much blank, so direction on how exactly the setup is done or any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! We have [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/index.html) available for the Elastic APM Python Agent. Just add `elastic-apm` to your `requirements.txt` and then follow the [onboarding instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/set-up.html) for whichever framework you're using. Our agent and the Elastic Stack are both fully [open source.](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python)

You can also start a no-credit-card-required trial with Elastic Cloud [here](https://cloud.elastic.co/registration?fromURI=%2Fhome) if you don't want to run the Elastic Stack yourself.